# Prevent user from hiding windows updates

Tags: windows, wsus, windows-update

Is there an option in GPO or registry to prevent users from hiding windows updates?

Comment: What do you mean by "hiding"? Do you want to prevent the user from postponing updates?

Comment: No. You can right click on an update and hide it so that windows won't show you this update again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of an option that specifically prevents a user from only the "hide" permission but you can explicitly remove all access to Windows Update via the Group Policy Editor (under User Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Update)

[image]

Additional information is here: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/88554-windows-update-enable-disable-access.html